# Set *all* IMG src values from containing A href values using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got a lot of these on a few webpages:

```
<td> <a href="http://www.colincooke.com/coin_images/colincookecol/1587.jpg" target="_blank" class="coinpic"><img src="../site_images/image.png" alt="image" /></a> </td>
```

And I'd like to use jQuery to set (change) all the src values for the img tag to the same as the href value on the containing a tag (on page load).

I've searched and so far hashed this together from what I've found which (probably obviously) doesn't work (set within $(document).ready(function() braces):

```
$('td').children('img')
.each(function(){
   url = $('img').attr('href');
    $('img').attr('src',url);
 });
```

What's the best way to do this or fix the above?

Comment: can you add a fiddle?  Would be nice to have something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify selectors further if you need to.

```js
$('a img').each(function (i, el) {
  el.src = el.parentNode.getAttribute('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="sample"><img src="foo" /></a>
<a href="sample2"><img src="bar" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sets the src on all images to match their parent `a`'s href:

```
$('a img').attr('src', function() {
  return $(this).parent('a').attr('href');
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/urycarqa/)

Comment: While I don't like the fact that you have to create a new jQuery object per each image on the page, this is a very jQuery way of doing it.